# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError problem, with a twist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following three models

LegacyRole:

```
class LegacyRole < LegacyModel
  has_many :permissions_roles
  has_many :permissions, :through => :permissions_roles
end
```

LegacyPermissionsRole:

```
class LegacyPermissionsRole < LegacyModel
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :permission
end
```

and LegacyPermission:

```
class LegacyPermission < LegacyModel
  has_many :permissions_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :permissions_roles
end
```

And in order for these to all work, and connect the legacy database and whatnot, I have the following class LegacyModel which is possibly trying to be too clever...

```
require 'active_record'

class LegacyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  establish_connection "legacy_#{::Rails.env}"

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    tabeleized_name = subclass.name.tableize
    raise "Legacy models must be prefixed with 'Legacy'" unless tabeleized_name.start_with?('legacy_')

    logger.info "***********LOAD***********"
    logger.info "Loaded legacy model: #{subclass.name} using table: #{tabeleized_name.gsub('legacy_', '')}"
    super
    subclass.set_table_name tabeleized_name.gsub('legacy_','')
  end


  # these methods do much the same thing, can probably abstract some of this out
  def self.belongs_to(association_id, options = {})
    new_association = association_id.to_s.insert(0, 'legacy_').to_sym
    old_association = association_id


    logger.info "Legacy model has belongs_to association: '#{association_id}'"
    association_id = association_id.to_s.insert(0, 'legacy_').to_sym
    logger.info "Converting association to: '#{association_id}'"

    unless options.has_key?(:foreign_key)  
      # our foreign_key is missing
      options[:foreign_key] = old_association.to_s.foreign_key
      logger.info("Foreign_key was missing, is now: #{options[:foreign_key]}")
    end

    super
    alias_method old_association, new_association
  end

  def self.has_many(association_id, options = {})
    new_association = association_id.to_s.insert(0, 'legacy_').to_sym
    old_association = association_id


    logger.info "Legacy model has_many to association: '#{association_id}'"
    association_id = association_id.to_s.insert(0, 'legacy_').to_sym
    logger.info "Converting association to: '#{association_id}'"
    logger.debug("Association options are: #{options.inspect}")

    if options.has_key?(:through)
      options[:through] = options[:through].to_s.insert(0, 'legacy_')
      logger.info("Through mutated, is now: #{options[:through]}")
    end

    super
    alias_method old_association, new_association
  end

end
```

Whenever I try to access permissions on an instance of LegacyRole, I get the following Active Record error: 
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association "legacy_permissions_roles" in model LegacyRole

I've stepped through all this as best I can and I really can't figure out why this is occurring, obviously with this being a bit more complicated than standard by the LegacyModel class I really don't know how to diagnose this further... I'm now at the point with it where I can't see the forest for the trees and feel it might just be something really simple that I've missed out!

**Edit:**

Here is the log output from the models loading

```
****************************
Loaded legacy model: LegacyPermission using table: permissions
Legacy model has_many association: 'permissions_roles'
Converting association to: 'legacy_permissions_roles'
Association options are: {}
Legacy model has_many association: 'roles'
Converting association to: 'legacy_roles'
Association options are: {:through=>:permissions_roles}
Changed :through to: 'legacy_permissions_roles'

****************************
Loaded legacy model: LegacyPermissionsRole using table: permissions_roles
Legacy model has belongs_to association: 'role'
Converting association to: 'legacy_role'
Legacy model has belongs_to association: 'permission'
Converting association to: 'legacy_permission'
Foreign_key was missing, is now: 'permission_id'

****************************
Loaded legacy model: LegacyRole using table: roles
Legacy model has_many association: 'permissions_roles'
Converting association to: 'legacy_permissions_roles'
Association options are: {}
Legacy model has_many association: 'permissions'
Converting association to: 'legacy_permissions'
Association options are: {:through=>:permissions_roles}
Changed :through to: 'legacy_permissions_roles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
class LegacyRole < LegacyModel
  has_many :permissions_roles
  has_many :permissions, :through => :legacy_permissions_roles # note the `legacy` prefix
end
```

Or was this a typo in your post?

Comment: That results in... Could not find the association "legacy_legacy_permissions_roles" in model LegacyRole :)

The association name is mutated in LegacyModel to prefix legacy_ so that everything wires up correctly with (well, hopefully) the minimal of fuss. 

I've a sneaking suspicion that rails is checking the class files source and finding an inconsistency due to this... not sure though!

Comment: Oops, I hadn't noticed that... Rails shouldn't be checking the class files though. At most, it should be checking the `schema.rb` file. You might want to try without the automatic prefixing, to see if that works (you never know...). Also, you probably want to inspect the model's reflections (I wrote about that briefly here: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/06/19/leveraging-active-record-reflections/) to see if the relationship is being registered properly.

Comment: If I don't change options[:through] in LegacyModel *AND* have :through => :legacy_permissions_roles in LegacyRole, I get Unknown column 'permissions_roles.legacy_role_id' which actually makes a modicum of sense (and should be easy enough to hack/fix), but that's just me doing by hand what LegacyModel should be doing automatically... Thanks though, I think your comments might be putting me on the right track!

Comment: Perhaps your issue is related to stripping 'legacy_' from the table name?

Comment: No.. the table names appear to be working, the legacy_role_id showing up will just be a key that's not being set properly somewhere... I'm sure this is an issue with wiring up options[:through], as without it, and done by hand it seems to work (ignoring the aforementioned key issue:))